# VBA. Сгруппировать значения через знак тире и запятую

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

Пишу макрос для Excel. Есть вот такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные в ней одинаковые, мне нужно, чтобы результат был `1-4, 7`, а у меня получается `1-7`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
Sub ГруппировкаИнвентарныхНомеров()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentGroup As String
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim groupStr As String
 
    ' Указываем имя листа, на котором находится таблица
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Заявка по сертификации")
    
    ' Определяем последнюю строку в столбце "№ по инв."
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Устанавливаем начальное значение группы
    currentGroup = ws.Cells(2, 2).Value
    
    ' Устанавливаем начальное значение для номера группы
    startRow = 2
 
    ' Проходим по строкам таблицы и выполняем группировку
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 3).Value And _
           ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 4).Value And _
           ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 5).Value And _
           ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 6).Value And _
           ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 7).Value Then
            ' Значения в указанных столбцах совпадают
            ' Продолжаем группировку
        Else
            ' Значения отличаются, завершаем текущую группу и начинаем новую
            If startRow <> i - 1 Then
                groupStr = currentGroup
                If i - startRow > 1 Then
                    groupStr = groupStr & "-" & ws.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value
                End If
                ws.Cells(startRow, 2).Value = groupStr
                ' Удаляем промежуточные строки
                ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & i - 1).Delete
                ' Корректируем номера строк и обновляем lastRow
                lastRow = lastRow - (i - startRow - 1)
                i = startRow ' Смещаемся к началу следующей группы
            End If
            ' Обновляем начальное значение для группы и номера группы
            currentGroup = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            startRow = i
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Обработка последней группы
    If startRow <> lastRow Then
        groupStr = currentGroup
        If lastRow - startRow > 0 Then
            groupStr = groupStr & "-" & ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value
        End If
        ws.Cells(startRow, 2).Value = groupStr
        ' Удаляем промежуточные строки
        ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & lastRow).Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, подробней о задаче. Иначе нам будет сложно понять код. Комментарии — это хорошо, но лучше полное условие.

Comment: "*есть вот такая таблица*" - неплохо было бы ее привести в вопросе

Comment: прикрепил изображения

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ Описывайте саму задачу, а не только свою попытку её решить.

Comment: Опишите задачу. Так получается, что нужно дополнительно проверять ``ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = (ws.Cells(i - 1, 2)+1)``  Но это догадки.

Comment: >> *Данные в ней одинаковые* === Если одинаковые, какой смысл гонять по пяти правым столбцам? Достаточно сгруппировать по инвентарным номерам. Но если в коде прописано, значит, данные могут отличаться? Точнее описывайте задачу.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ГруппировкаИнвентарныхНомеров()
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, groupstr As String
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Заявка по сертификации")
    j = 4
    k = .Cells(j - 1, 2)
    i = k
    groupstr = "'" & k
    Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(j, 1))
        If .Cells(j, 3) = .Cells(j - 1, 3) And _
           .Cells(j, 4) = .Cells(j - 1, 4) And _
           .Cells(j, 5) = .Cells(j - 1, 5) And _
           .Cells(j, 6) = .Cells(j - 1, 6) And _
           .Cells(j, 7) = .Cells(j - 1, 7) Then
        k = k + 1
        If .Cells(j, 2) > k Then
          If i < k - 1 Then groupstr = groupstr & "-" & k - 1
          groupstr = groupstr & ", " & .Cells(j, 2)
          k = .Cells(j, 2)
          i = k
        End If
        .Rows(j).Delete
      Else
        If i < k Then groupstr = groupstr & "-" & k
        .Cells(j - 1, 2) = groupstr
        .Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(j - 1, 1) + 1
        k = .Cells(j, 2)
        groupstr = "'" & k
        j = j + 1
        i = k
      End If
    Loop
    If i < k Then groupstr = groupstr & "-" & k
    .Cells(j - 1, 2) = groupstr
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку на строке ```k = Cells(j - 1, 2)```. Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: Переделал, видимо, это было из-за отсуствия ссылки на ws.

Comment: И чего? Как успехи?